# Unity acting bit different

Tags: unity, 16.04, kernel, lts

I am using 16.04LTS and after a recent kernel upgrade my desktop behavior changed. I have the list of software I use, vertically on the left of the screen. When I open apps in various workspaces everything  works well. When I want to switch to another workspace I used to click the app's icon on the left of the screen and automatically move to related workspace. Now it does not work as it used to, I have to click the workspace switcher and then choose to workspace that the app, that I want to use, is active on. How can I correct this?

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: did you upgrade from 11.04 or earlier?

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `uname -a`?